# JavaScript get info from object

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript [object](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=92e5810792f880f23d3ea6a043577f3a). I try to get `classid` from `rgInventory.(someid).classid` and always getting `undefined`.

My code (items is my object):

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(items.rgInventory).length; i++) {   
    console.log(items.rgInventory[i].classid);
}
```

Comment: @bluetoft It's a typo, which could have been solved in about ten seconds by simply examining the relevant variables in a debugger. That's the textbook definition of "not useful".

Comment: console.log(items.rgInventory['1908569708'].classid);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `i` is not the key, but the sequence number of that key.

Change your code to:

```
var keys = Object.keys(items.rgInventory);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {   
    console.log(items.rgInventory[keys[i]].classid);
}
```

Note that with the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax, it can be coded like this:

```
for (var key of Object.keys(items.rgInventory)) {   
    console.log(items.rgInventory[key].classid);
}
```

The [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) syntax is more appropriate for iterating over object keys:

```
for (var key in items.rgInventory) {   
    console.log(items.rgInventory[key].classid);
}
```

You could also use the `forEach` callback, with the nice second argument for setting `this`:

```
Object.keys(items.rgInventory).forEach(function (key) {   
    console.log(this[key].classid);
}, items.rgInventory);
```

Comment: Could the down-voter please explain what the issue is?

Comment: I like using `for...of`, but in this case isn't it identical to (and more wordy than) `for (let key in items.rgInventory)`?

Comment: @torazaburo, they are different and have a different purpose: `for...of` gives the key values, while `for ... in` gives the sequence number of them (i.e, 0, 1, 2, ...), which is less useful in this case.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this is an object, not an array, so `for...in` will precisely give the key values. Doing so is its entire raison d'etre.

Comment: @torazaburo, you are right of course, I missed the point that you were not iterating over `Object.keys`. `for ...in` is definitely the better way!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're using the `i` variable as a lookup, instead of `Object.keys(items.rgInventory)[i]`

try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(items.rgInventory).length; i++) {   
    console.log(items.rgInventory[Object.keys(items.rgInventory)[i]].classid);
}
```

But that is probably not how you want to do this lookup... This is a little cleaner:

```
Object.keys(items.rgInventory).forEach(function(key) {
     console.log(items.rgInventory[key].classid)
})
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain his issue with ALL the answers?